# GMock: Has to be always pure virtual the base class of a mock class?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have read about good practices in googlecode. And they are right, but I'm still curious about  the following:

There is some class definition, lets say:

```
class A{
   virtual void method_a(){}
};
```

as you can see, **method_a** is **not pure vitual**.

Can I code

```
class MockA: public A{
    MOCK_METHOD(method_a, void());
};
```

with no dark results?

Even further. Can I override **method_a** in **MockA** ?

Like:

```
class MockA: public A{
    void method_a(){
        // Do something here.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just did a test, and it seems we can. I'm using that approach in order to test some class functions with more that 10 parameters.

According to [Simplifying the Interface without Breaking Existing Code](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#simplifying-the-interface-without-breaking-existing-code). From gmock cookbook.

For instance:

```
class SomeClass {
     ...
     virtual void bad_designed_func(int a, ...){ // This functions has up to 12 parameters.
                                                 // The others were omitted for simplicity.
};


class MockSomeClass: public SomeClass {
    ...
    void bad_designed_func(int a, ...){ // This functions recives 12 parameters.
                                        // The others were omitted for simplicity.
        ...   
        test_wat_i_want(a);  // Mock method call. I'm only interest in paramater a.
    }

    MOCK_METHOD1(test_wat_i_want, void(int a));
};
```

In my code, I don't have any abstract class (meaning no pure virtual functions at all). **This, it's not a recommended approach but helps us to deal with legacy code.**